# how to compare these string and webelement

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
String result=driver.findElement(
          By.id("sys_original.incident.number")).getAttribute("value");

WebElement a=driver.findElement(By.xpath(
            "/html/body/div[1]/div/span/div/nav/div/span/div/div/input"));
a.sendKeys(result);
```

I need coding to compare these string and webelement in webdriver.Both must display same answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that what you are really trying to do there because the same result is you are passing in 2nd element too. Still if you want a code which match the string then refer below code

```
       if(result.equalsIgnoreCase(2ndvalue))
        {
            System.out.println("String is same");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("String is not same");
        }
```

Replace `2ndvalue` with your string variable or string.

To extract text from Element you need to use `.getText()` method

Now suppose 2ndvalue is Element then use

```
2ndvalue.getText()
```

If you just want to verify if the string is same or not for your testcase then you can use asserts please refer below link :-

Using testng:-

http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/assertions-in-testng

If you are using JUNIT:-

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_using_assertion.htm

Hope it will help you

Comment: First of all thanks for accepting the answer ... if think NickQ mean with assert.. if you just want to validate the string and do not want any condition accroing to result then you can also use asserts.. I have added the refer of same in my answer as well.